# Backbone.js - Access referrer in controller function

Tags: backbone.js, referrer

I have a list of products (index view) and when a user clicks on a product, a Lightbox opens (show view). Now, when the user closes the lightbox, I want to redirect him back to the page he came from. The problem is that the Lightbox might have been opened from several different places. It's best demonstrated with an example:

Product "Foo" appears on 3 different pages:

```
/                  (the home page)
/tag/bar           (all products tagged with "bar")
/tag/baz/page-3    (all products tagged with "baz", paginated)
```

Now I have to decide where to redirect the user when the Lightbox closes. At this stage, there is no information available about which page the Lightbox was opened from.

So I figured I save a "returnTo" path when opening the Lightbox (rendering the show view).
In the controller function, which is triggered by the hash change and renders the show view, I can't seem to get to any "referrer" information, though.

Is there any way to see what page triggered the hash change?
Or is there a better way to solve this problems?

All suggestions are appreciated! :)

EDIT:

I solved the problem by setting a cookie.
The cookie is set anytime a index site (might be any of the three mentioned above) is visited. Then, when the Lightbox is closed, the user is redirected to the cookie value, which is the last opened index site.
It would be great, though, if there was a way built in to Backbone.js to "remember" pathes somehow. Julien mentioned in one of the comments that it might be possible to add such functionality.

Comment: Wait, you're using a lightbox, and when the user closes it, you reload the page?  Why?  Isn't he on the page already, and the lightbox is a just a javascript-generated DIV z-indexed above the rest of your content?  Can't you just banish the DIV when you're done and let the user go back to his business?

Comment: That's what I am guessing he does but he accesses it with a hash location.

Comment: No, I have to rerender the index view when the Lightbox closes, because the user might have come directly to the show view, meaning that the index view has not been rendered properly yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the browser back button within JS. Assuming you set everything right, the browser should go back to the previous set hash and voila.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. Problem is that the user might have come from a completely different URL and entered the URL to the show view by hand (unlikely, but possible). Or maybe he clicked on the link in an email and there is no "back"...

Comment: Change Backbone.History to keep track of history for you and go back to that state.

Comment: Yes, that sounds good! How can I do that? Can't find anything inbuilt in Backbone.history for that...

Comment: You can override saveLocation for that.

Comment: I had a look at the sourcecode but couldn't figure out how I could override saveLocation to achieve that. Could you elaborate? Has this been done before?

Comment: I would rarely recommend overriding a framework method, I do not think doing so is the best solution.  If/when backbone.js changes the history functionality and you do an update, you may find that your override is problematic.